# added views now showing up to inherited LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a class that extends LinearLayout that I add some views to in the constructor. However the views I add don't show up. What am I doing wrong?

I set the background resource to the color green. And I do see a large green square. So the layout is showing up itself.

thanks!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class SuperButton extends LinearLayout 
{

private ImageView buttonImage;
private TextView label;
private Context context;
public SuperButton(Context context, 
        String text,
        int imageResource,
        int backgroundResource) 
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    this.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);

    this.label = new  TextView(context);
    this.label.setText("test test test ");

    this.label.setBackgroundColor(0xff0f0f0f);
    this.buttonImage = new ImageView(context);
    this.buttonImage.setImageResource(imageResource);

    this.buttonImage.setLayoutParams(new 
            LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));       
    this.label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(100,100));      

    this.addView(label);    
    this.addView(buttonImage);

}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
}

public void setButtonImage(ImageView buttonImage) 
{
    this.buttonImage = buttonImage;
}

public ImageView getButtonImage() 
{
    return buttonImage;
}

public void setLabel(TextView label) 
{
    this.label = label;
}

public TextView getLabel() 
{
    return label;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the override for onLayout that was generated by default did not call it's super. this solved the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
     super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to use hierarchy viewer to see the info in your view tree.  You will likely find your answer there.

Comment: hierarchy viewer is unable to debug the device. i think because it has a production build on it.